# What is the earliest paper in which graph vertex connectivity is denoted by the Greek letter $\kappa$?

Tags: mathematics-social-history, graph-theory

I'm wondering how far back this notation goes. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around a bit after this question was posted on MSE, and the earliest reference I found is in Harary's 1962 paper [The maximum connectivity of a graph](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.48.7.1142). Here,

> A graph $G$ is called $n$-connected if G has at least $n + 1$ points and it is impossible to disconnect $G$ by removing $n - 1$ or fewer points. The connectivity of $G$, denoted $\kappa (G)$, is defined to be $n$ if $G$ is $n$-connected but not $(n + 1)$-connected.

Harary's paper doesn't seem to suggest that Harary was the one to come up with this notation. The paper has only two citations:

- Whitney's [*Congruent graphs and the connectivity of graphs*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2972-8_4), the 1932 paper defining connectivity; this does *not* use the notation $\kappa(G)$.
- Berge's 1958 textbook *Théorie des graphes et ses applications*, which could plausibly be the source of the notation; I am unable to check.

Berge's textbook is, as Harary mentions, the "second book on graph theory ever written". The first is presumably König's *Theorie der endlichen und unendlichen Graphen*, from 1936, which has a chapter on cut vertices and cut sets, but does not use the notation $\kappa(G)$; I don't think it even defines connectivity.